# Как передать значения от потомков к родителю?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

есть древовидный объект, с множетсвом вложенностей, мне необходимо передать значения от нижних потомков к родителю, как это можно сделать?
пример объекта:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentid": null,
    "count": "0",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parentid": 1,
        "count": "89",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "parentid": 2,
            "count": "19",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 5,
                "parentid": 3,
                "count": "205"
              },
              {
                "id": 4,
                "parentid": 3,
                "count": "8"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

результат выполнения, каждый родитель получает сумму своих потомков:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то я не вижу в примере данных, что бы *каждый родитель получает сумму своих потомков*

Comment: необходимо передать count от потомков к родителю и суммировать значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополнил ваш пример для наглядности.
Рекурсивно проходим по потомкам, если есть дети - запускаем функцию для них, иначе - пробрасываем `count`.

```js
var o = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentid": null,
    "count": "0",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parentid": 1,
        "count": "89",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "parentid": 2,
            "count": "19",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 5,
                "parentid": 3,
                "count": "205"
              },
              {
                "id": 4,
                "parentid": 3,
                "count": "8"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 6,
            "parentid": 2,
            "count": "20"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

calcCount(o);
console.log(o);

function calcCount(ob) {
 if(ob.length) {
  var sum = 0;
  ob.forEach(function(a) {
   if(a.children) {
    a.count = calcCount(a.children);
   }
   sum += +a.count;
  });
  return sum;
 }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, только вы забыли добавить count родителя)`a.count = parseInt(a.count) + calcCount(a.children);`

Comment: Неочевидно было, что изначальный `count` родителя тоже должен участвовать в суммировании.